# Improve terrible array logic

Tags: php, arrays, refactoring

I'm working on a Roulette simulator for fun. I have an array of the numbers on a wheel, in the order they appear on the wheel;

```
public static $number = [
    0 => ['colour' => 'green', 'value' => 0],
    1 => ['colour' => 'red', 'value' => 32],
    2 => ['colour' => 'black', 'value' => 15],
    3 => ['colour' => 'red', 'value' => 19],
    4 => ['colour' => 'black', 'value' => 4],
    5 => ['colour' => 'red', 'value' => 21],
    6 => ['colour' => 'black', 'value' => 2],
    7 => ['colour' => 'red', 'value' => 25],
    8 => ['colour' => 'black', 'value' => 17],
    9 => ['colour' => 'red', 'value' => 34],
    10 => ['colour' => 'black', 'value' => 6],
```

Up to 36. I want to make a "and the neighbours" function that will pull out the "neighbours" either-side of a given number. Eg. If "2" is selected then returned will be a sub-section of the above array;

```
[
    4 => ['colour' => 'black', 'value' => 4],
    5 => ['colour' => 'red', 'value' => 21],
    6 => ['colour' => 'black', 'value' => 2],
    7 => ['colour' => 'red', 'value' => 25],
    8 => ['colour' => 'black', 'value' => 17],
];
```

So my function is the following;

```
public static function getNeighbours($number)
{
    $key = array_search($number, array_column(self::$number, 'value'));

    $output = [];

    if ($key == 0) {
        $output[] = self::$number[35];
        $output[] = self::$number[36];
        $output[] = self::$number[0];
        $output[] = self::$number[1];
        $output[] = self::$number[2];
    } else if ($key == 1) {
        $output[] = self::$number[36];
        $output[] = self::$number[0];
        $output[] = self::$number[1];
        $output[] = self::$number[2];
        $output[] = self::$number[3];
    } else if ($key == 35) {
        $output[] = self::$number[33];
        $output[] = self::$number[34];
        $output[] = self::$number[35];
        $output[] = self::$number[36];
        $output[] = self::$number[0];
    } else if ($key == 36) {
        $output[] = self::$number[34];
        $output[] = self::$number[35];
        $output[] = self::$number[36];
        $output[] = self::$number[0];
        $output[] = self::$number[1];
    } else {

        if (isset(self::$number[$key - 2])) {
            $output[] = self::$number[$key - 2];
        }

        if (isset(self::$number[$key - 1])) {
            $output[] = self::$number[$key - 1];
        }

        $output[] = self::$number[$key];

        if (isset(self::$number[$key + 1])) {
            $output[] = self::$number[$key + 1];
        }

        if (isset(self::$number[$key + 2])) {
            $output[] = self::$number[$key + 2];
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

It works fine. And even accounts for if a low or high number is chosen (probably helps if you know the term "and the neighbours".

But it's not very elegant. How can I make this function a **lot** smaller?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some elegant math that will help you, `37` is total number of elements you have in array. You can replace it with `count($array)` for example.

```
function getNeighbourKeys($i) 
{
    return  [
        (($i - 2 + 37) % 37),     // index of the one before previous
        (($i - 1 + 37) % 37),     // index of a previous element
        $i,                       // index of your element
        ($i + 1) % 37,            // index of a next element
        ($i + 2) % 37             // index of the one after next
    ];
}
```

After that:

```
$output = [];
$keys = getNeighbourKeys($i);
foreach ($keys as $k) {
    if (isset(self::$number[$k])) {
        $output[] = self::$number[$k];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you google "roulette number colors" Google will say "The pockets of the roulette wheel are numbered from 0 to 36. In number ranges from 1 to 10 and 19 to 28, odd numbers are red and even are black. In ranges from 11 to 18 and 29 to 36, odd numbers are black and even are red. There is a green pocket numbered 0 (zero)" which is easy to implement as a function like so:

```
function number($i) {
      if ($i == 0) { //There's a variant with "00" I think
         return [ "color" => "green", "number" => $i ];
      } elseif (($i >= 1 && $i <= 10) || ($i >= 19 && $i <= 28)) {
         return [ "color" => ($i%2==0?"red":"black"), "number" => $i ];
      } else {
         return [ "color" => ($i%2==0?"black":"red"), "number" => $i ];
      } 
}
```

Now the neighbours are a sliding window of 2 above and below the number so they're:

```
  public static function getNeighbours($number) {
        $output = [];
        for ($i = ($number-2)%37;$i <= ($number+2)%37;$i = ($i+1)%37) {
            $output[] = self::number($i);
        }
        return $output;

  }
```

This is the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm to refactor your code would be like this:

- Get the superset range of keys from `self::$number` array, like this

  ```
  $totalCount = count(self::$number);
  $supersetRange = range(0, $totalCount - 1);
  ```
- Search for the key from `self::$number` array based on the value `$number` passed to the function, like this:

  ```
  $key = array_search($number, array_column(self::$number, 'value'));
  ```
- Get the subset range of keys from the `self::$number` array based on the key derived above, like this:

  ```
  $subsetRange = range($key - 2, $key + 2);
  ```
- Now adjust this subset range of keys, if necessary, using the following `foreach` loop,

  ```
  foreach($subsetRange as $p){
      if($p < 0){
          array_shift($subsetRange);
          if(in_array($subsetRange[count($subsetRange) - 1] + 1, $supersetRange)){
              $subsetRange[] = $subsetRange[count($subsetRange) - 1] + 1;
          }
      }elseif($p > $totalCount - 1){
          array_pop($subsetRange);
          if(in_array($subsetRange[0] - 1, $supersetRange)){
              array_unshift($subsetRange, $subsetRange[0] - 1);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Now push the appropriate elements of `self::$number` array to `$output` array based on the above subset range of keys, like this:

  ```
  $output = array();
  foreach($subsetRange as $key){
      $output[] = self::$number[$key];
  }
  ```
- Finally return this `$output` array from your static method,

  ```
  return $output;
  ```

So **the complete** code of `getNeighbours()` method would be like this:

```
public static function getNeighbours($number){
    $totalCount = count(self::$number);
    $supersetRange = range(0, $totalCount - 1);
    $key = array_search($number, array_column(self::$number, 'value'));
    $subsetRange = range($key - 2, $key + 2);
    foreach($subsetRange as $p){
        if($p < 0){
            array_shift($subsetRange);
            if(in_array($subsetRange[count($subsetRange) - 1] + 1, $supersetRange)){
                $subsetRange[] = $subsetRange[count($subsetRange) - 1] + 1;
            }
        }elseif($p > $totalCount - 1){
            array_pop($subsetRange);
            if(in_array($subsetRange[0] - 1, $supersetRange)){
                array_unshift($subsetRange, $subsetRange[0] - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    $output = array();
    foreach($subsetRange as $key){
        $output[] = self::$number[$key];
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple, step by step and expressive approach;

```
public static function getNeighbours($number)
{
    // get the key
    $key = array_search($number, array_column(self::$number, 'value'));

    // determine range of keys
    $range = range($key - 2, $key + 2);
    $output = [];

    foreach ($range as $k => $item) {
        // keep the values inside the range
        if ($item < 0) {
            $item = 37 + $item;
        } else if ($item > 36) {
            $item = $item - 37;
        }
        // add section to the output
        $output[] = self::$number[$item];
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the number of the items of your initial array as a *divisor* in arithmetic ***modulo*** operator:

```
public static function getNeighbours($value) {
    $key = array_search($value, array_column(self::$number, 'value'));
    $divisor = count(self::$number);
    $neighbours = [];

    foreach ([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2] as $step) {
        $divident = (($d = ($key + $step)) < 0)? $divisor + $d : $d;
        $neighbours[] = self::$number[$divident % $divisor];
    }

    return $neighbours;    
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php